# String is not in correct format C#

Tags: c#

I am using the code below.

```
MySiteScript = String.Format("$mysiteHostUrl = \"{0}\"; 
$personalSiteGlobalAdminDisplayName = \"SharePoint Admin\"; 
$mysite = Get-SPSite $mysiteHostUrl; 
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($mysite); 
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);  
$AllProfiles = $upm.GetEnumerator(); 
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles) 
{
    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName; 
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value;   
    if($AccountName -like \"{1}\") 
    { 
        if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null) 
        { 
            $profile.CreatePersonalSite();  
        } 
        else  
        { 
            Write-Host \"Personal site already exists.\" ;  
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host \"User not found.\";  
    }  
} 
$mysite.Dispose()", mySiteHostUrl, sAMAccountName);
```

Getting an error:
**The string is not in correct format.**

What is the problem?What do you suggest?

Comment: Format your code. Can *you* read what you've posted?

Comment: That looks horribly hard to manage and debug.

Comment: I also see you've asked several questions but accepted no answers. People will be more likely to answer your questions if you reward them for doing so. If you feel an answer has been added that best resolves your issue, click the check mark to the left of it to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use multi-line string literal i.e. [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
MySiteScript = String.Format(@"$mysiteHostUrl ...
...
...$mysite.Dispose()", mySiteHostUrl, sAMAccountName);
```

Note - you can't use backslash escaping for double quotes in verbatim string. Use [quote-escape-sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) (two consecutive double-quote characters). Complete sample:

```
dMySiteScript = String.Format(@"$mysiteHostUrl = ""{0}""; 
$personalSiteGlobalAdminDisplayName = ""SharePoint Admin""; 
$mysite = Get-SPSite $mysiteHostUrl; 
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($mysite); 
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);  
$AllProfiles = $upm.GetEnumerator(); foreach($profile in $AllProfiles) {{$DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName; 
$AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value;   
if($AccountName -like ""{1}"") 
  {{ 
    if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null) {{ $profile.CreatePersonalSite();  
    }} else  {{ 
        Write-Host ""Personal site already exists."" ;  }} 
  }} else {{ 
     Write-Host ""User not found."";  }}  
}}  $mysite.Dispose()", mySiteHostUrl, sAMAccountName);
```

Comment: So basically we actually ARE using C#, just a string format, to build a PowerShell script. Funny.

Comment: I have done as you mentioned. However getting the same error.

Comment: @user949235 sorry, didn't notice curly braces in your format string. They also should be doubled, otherwise opening curly brace considered as start of parameter placeholder. See update